# can't livestream on facebook as 720p when using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ffmpeg, facebook-live-api

I just realized that when we using facebook api to create a livestream ( /me/live_videos ) , we only get 360p as output max even we sent 1080p. But, if we use Facebook dialog, we can get to 720p, the same video input.

```
FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'live_broadcast',
    phase: 'create',
}, function(response) {
    FB.ui({
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'live_broadcast',
      phase: 'publish',
      broadcast_data: response
    }, function(response) {
    });
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/

Does anyone know how to get 720p when we use Facebook graph API ?

Comment: It's not your code.  Facebook isn't always going to run your stream in HD... it depends on a lot of factors.